# Unique rows for repeated measures ANOVA from summary table

Tags: r, dplyr, anova, tibble

I want to run a repeated measures ANOVA with `rstatix::anova_test()`.

My data is:

```
tb <- tibble(id = factor(rep(1:100, each = 8)),
       area = factor(rep(c(4,2,3,1,5,3,1,5), 100)),
       score = round(runif(800, 1, 7), 0)
)
```

I want to use this formula: `anova_test(data = tb, dv = score, wid = id, within = area)`.

There are multiple instances for some combinations of `id` and `area`. In these cases, I want to use the `mean` of `score` for this combination as the value for the `dv`.

I tried solving this as follows:

```
tbs <- tb %>% 
  group_by(id, area) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_score = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
anova_test(data = tbs, dv = mean_score, wid = id, within = area)
```

However, I am getting an error stating that the column `id` doesn't exist. Obviously, the column does exist and each row contains a unique combination of `id` and `area` now, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an `%>% ungroup()` before running the `anova_test()`.